# Hide check boxes and make labels clickable. JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I hide the original checkboxes and make the labels be clickable and act like checkboxes? I am sure there is a way to do it in JS! I am loading the labels and the checkboxes with PHP, they are loaded dynamically and can always be different, depending on what the user chooses prior to this page. Thanks!

```
                foreach ($row as $type) { ?>
                   <label for="<?php echo $type['id'] ?>" class="interests-span">
                        <h3><?php echo $type['Type'] ?></h3>
                    </label>
                    <input id="<?php echo $type['id'] ?>" type="checkbox" style="display:block;" value="<?php echo $type['Type']?>" name="options[]"/>
                    <?php
                }
```

[image]

Comment: labels link to the input by id. Where is the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: Labels should be linked with id or name.

Here is custom implementation what you want.
But I don't think it is correct to select checkbox with only values

```
foreach ($row as $type) { ?>
     <label for="<?php echo $type['Type'] ?>" class="interests-span" 
        onclick="toggleCheckboxFromLabel('<?php echo $type['Type'] ?>')"
     >
          <h3><?php echo $type['Type'] ?></h3>
     </label>
     <input type="checkbox" style="display:block;" value="<?php echo $type['Type']?>" 
           name="options[]"/>
<?php } ?>

<script>
function toggleCheckboxFromLabel(val){
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + val + '"]')
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id equals to the for attribute.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($row as $type) { ?>
  <label for="<?= 'checkbox_' . $counter ?>" class="interests-span">
      <h3><?php echo $type['Type'] ?></h3>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" style="display:none;" id="<?= 'checkbox_' . $counter ?>" value="<?php echo $type['Type']?>" 
        name="options[]"/>
<?php
   $counter++;
} ?>
```